# How to specify the column coordinates in tabula command line

Tags: java, tabula

I want table data from PDF and I am using below command to get table data

```
java -jar tabula-java.jar -a 301.95,14.85,841.0500000000001,695.25 -t example.pdf
```

But in this, two column data get mixed in some rows,
so I want to specify column coordinates for getting the perfect data,
but I don't know how to get column coordinate,
so anyone can guide me with perfect command would be helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the column coordinates using the -c or --columns parameter. The coordinates you specify will be the coordinates of the delineators between columns. So if one column goes from 10.5 to 13.5 and the next column goes from 13.5 to 17.5 then you only list 13.5. You will also need to turn guess off. You didn't provide an example pdf so I can't provide you with the correct coordinates but your command would look something like this:

```
java -jar tabula-java.jar -a 301.95,14.85,841.0500000000001,695.25 -c 15.7,17.3,19.2,33.2,70.1,100.7,200.6,300.7 -t example.pdf -g False
```

You can read more about the different options for getting your command just right from the help command:

```
    $ java -jar target/tabula-1.0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar --help
usage: tabula [-a <AREA>] [-b <DIRECTORY>] [-c <COLUMNS>] [-d] [-f
       <FORMAT>] [-g] [-h] [-i] [-l] [-n] [-o <OUTFILE>] [-p <PAGES>] [-r]
       [-s <PASSWORD>] [-t] [-u] [-v]

Tabula helps you extract tables from PDFs

 -a,--area <AREA>           Portion of the page to analyze
                            (top,left,bottom,right). Example: --area
                            269.875,12.75,790.5,561. Default is entire
                            page
 -b,--batch <DIRECTORY>     Convert all .pdfs in the provided directory.
 -c,--columns <COLUMNS>     X coordinates of column boundaries. Example
                            --columns 10.1,20.2,30.3
 -d,--debug                 Print detected table areas instead of
                            processing.
 -f,--format <FORMAT>       Output format: (CSV,TSV,JSON). Default: CSV
 -g,--guess                 Guess the portion of the page to analyze per
                            page.
 -h,--help                  Print this help text.
 -i,--silent                Suppress all stderr output.
 -l,--lattice               Force PDF to be extracted using lattice-mode
                            extraction (if there are ruling lines
                            separating each cell, as in a PDF of an Excel
                            spreadsheet)
 -n,--no-spreadsheet        [Deprecated in favor of -t/--stream] Force PDF
                            not to be extracted using spreadsheet-style
                            extraction (if there are no ruling lines
                            separating each cell)
 -o,--outfile <OUTFILE>     Write output to <file> instead of STDOUT.
                            Default: -
 -p,--pages <PAGES>         Comma separated list of ranges, or all.
                            Examples: --pages 1-3,5-7, --pages 3 or
                            --pages all. Default is --pages 1
 -r,--spreadsheet           [Deprecated in favor of -l/--lattice] Force
                            PDF to be extracted using spreadsheet-style
                            extraction (if there are ruling lines
                            separating each cell, as in a PDF of an Excel
                            spreadsheet)
 -s,--password <PASSWORD>   Password to decrypt document. Default is empty
 -t,--stream                Force PDF to be extracted using stream-mode
                            extraction (if there are no ruling lines
                            separating each cell)
 -u,--use-line-returns      Use embedded line returns in cells. (Only in
                            spreadsheet mode.)
 -v,--version               Print version and exit.
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what is the unit that use for the columns (pixels?) and what is a practical way to get your column sizes from a document?    Thanks!!!

Comment: Purely anecdotal, but I think the measurement numbers represent pixels (@72dpi).
You can get quick measurements by using the [Tabula GUI](https://github.com/tabulapdf/tabula) and exporting a template.  refer the dimensions in that exported json.

Comment: ^^ How I arrived at this anecdote ^^ : 
If you look at many Git issues, they mention the numbers as referring to "pt".
This means one "point" of arbitrary measurement. Commonly, at 72ppi, 1pt==1px

Comment: To determine the proper spacing for area or columns input, open the pdf in Adobe Acrobat, turn on rulers, and set it to Points. Zoom way the heck in, and you can see the exact point measurements to split the area/tables on.